# jQuery validator not working with repeating fields

Tags: jquery, knockout.js, jquery-validate

I'm using http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-validation/ for validation in my MVC app.

I have a repeating text input (bound using knockout) that is marked as required:

```
<form id="myForm" class="validate_form" method="get" action="">

<input type="text" class="required error txtOrder" maxlength="4000" 
placeholder="Please enter your order..." data-bind="{ attr: { 
id: viewModel.orderID }}" />
```

1. There are 10 rows.
2. I click "Save" and it blocks the form, saying that the field is required.
3. I enter some text in the field next to the error message, leaving the other 9 rows empty.
4. I click "Save" and the validator thinks that the form is now valid and allows the form to be submitted.

What am I doing wrong? Or does the jQuery validator not work with knockout? If so, is there a professional-looking jQuery plugin that will work with knockout?

Thank you for your assistance.

Comment: does rows have the same name attribute? in your code i don't see name attribute. this is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input` shown has no `name` which is required to submit field and validator plugin uses `name` to identify fields also